# Postgres database not connecting to flask app (connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working on a flask/Angular project using a postgres database. When I run my docker-conpose.yml  the backend stops and displays this error.

connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Although when I test connecting to the database using the URL in the docker-compose.yml (postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/onlineexam-database-1), on TablePlus I can connect.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  #Backend build
  api:
    build: ./Backend
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    expose: 
      - "5432"
    environment:
      Stage: development
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/onlineexam-database-1
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@database/
    volumes:
        - .:/code

  #Frontend Build
  web:
    build: ./frontend
    image: frontend
    container_name: frontend
    restart: always
    environment:
        PORT: 4200
        PROXY_API: http://quizme:5000/
        API_URL: 'http://localhost:5000'
    ports:
    - "4200:80"
   # expose: 
  #  - "4200"
    
  #DB build
  database:
    
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: onlineexam-database-1
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data=rwx/
```

Here is my app.py. The command entities.entity.Base.metadata.create_all(entities.entity.engine) is where the error occurs.

```
# creating the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


CORS(app)


oauth = OAuth(app)

# if needed, generate database schema
entities.entity.Base.metadata.create_all(entities.entity.engine)

auth0 = oauth.register(
    'auth0',
    client_id='kYsfByzSV4rxmTJSX6jmaQumLeJZVjoM',
    client_secret='fDR6hxNSGJApKrxTdZyD2EC4ezV6oV4F5AlM_lm_Pvgb8UijifazIeJ8b3HzBEUL',
    api_base_url='https://dev-4-frsuj0.us.auth0.com',
    access_token_url='https://dev-4-frsuj0.us.auth0.com/oauth/token',
    authorize_url='https://dev-4-frsuj0.us.auth0.com/authorize',
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'Manage exams',
    },
)

# Routes for login, callback 
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return auth0.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri='http://localhost:5000')

@app.route('/callback')
def callback_handling():
    # Handles response from token endpoint
    auth0.authorize_access_token()
    resp = auth0.get('userinfo')
    userinfo = resp.json()

    # Store the user information in flask session.
    session['jwt_payload'] = userinfo
    session['profile'] = {
        'user_id': userinfo['sub'],
        'name': userinfo['name'],
        'picture': userinfo['picture']
    }
    return redirect('/dashboard')

@app.route('/exams')
def get_exams():
    # fetching from the database
    session = entities.entity.Session()
    exam_objects = session.query(entities.exam.Exam).all()

    # transforming into JSON-serializable objects
    schema = entities.exam.ExamSchema(many=True)
    exams = schema.dump(exam_objects)

    # serializing as JSON
    session.close()
    return jsonify(exams)


@app.route('/exams', methods=['POST'])
@auth.requires_auth
def add_exam():
    # mount exam object
    posted_exam = entities.exam.ExamSchema(only=('title', 'description'))\
        .load(request.get_json())

    exam = entities.exam.Exam(**posted_exam, created_by="HTTP post request")

    # persist exam
    session = entities.entity.Session()
    session.add(exam)
    session.commit()

    # return created exam
    new_exam = entities.exam.ExamSchema().dump(exam).data
    session.close()
    return jsonify(new_exam), 201

@app.errorhandler(auth.AuthError)
def handle_auth_error(ex):
    response = jsonify(ex.error)
    response.status_code = ex.status_code
    return response
```

My entity.py. This is where I create the engine and bind it.

```
# coding=utf-8

from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, DateTime,Table,MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


#Database variables
db_url = 'localhost:5432'
db_name = 'onlineexam-database-1'
db_user = 'postgres'
db_password = 'postgres'

#Connect to database through sqlalchemy
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_url}/{db_name}')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class Entity():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime)
    last_updated_by = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, created_by):
        self.created_at = datetime.now()
        self.updated_at = datetime.now()
        self.last_updated_by = created_by
```

config.py and env.dev

```
import os


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite://")
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_APP=src:app.py
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://online_exam:online_exam@db:5432/online_exam_dev
```

nginx/conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://app:8000;
    }
    location /hit {
        proxy_pass   http://app:8000/visitor;
    }
    location /hit/reset {
        proxy_pass   http://app:8000/visitor/reset;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13
COPY conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
ENV FLASK_APP=/backend/src/app/__init__.py
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN pip3 install pipenv
RUN pip3 install psycopg2-binary
RUN pipenv install sqlalchemy psycopg2-binary

EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /src

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

When accessing a container from inside other containers, please use the docker-compose service name. In your case is `database`

So try this url:

`postgresql://postgres:postgres@database:5432/onlineexam-database-1`

See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/